# Trying to read file input as well as do file output after the original file has been reversed?

Tags: java, file, exception, input

I have read my book and what my teacher has made slides on the subject of read and write methods using Exceptions like FileNotFoundException. I have written a good bit of the code and got it working to allow me to ask the user for a file path and to read this file and display it on the console. I'm struggling as to reverse the file text and to output this new text to a file to save/create. My book does not explain how to do both a read and write method on the same program. So the code I have written to do output is probably very wrong. I searched some on the internet for help but did not find anything that could help me since I want to allow the user to input what file locations they want to read and write to.

I am wanting : 
1. Create a class that allows the user to selecct a file name and output the contents of the file to the console. Recommend using a text file to display, java files are text files. You may want to put this code in a method to allow you to complete the remainder of this assignment without overwriting your code.
a. Asking the user to enter the full path to your file to make certain you are processing the correct file.
2. Modify your code/add a method to display the contents of the file in reverse order. You do not need to reverse the characters on each line but simply out put the lines of the file in reverse order.
a. Read the content of the file into an ArrayList and then traverse the ArrayList.
3. Finally, copy the contents of the file to another file. You will need to loop through the file and write each line to a new file.
I also want to create a new exception, FileMissingException which will extend FileNotFoundException. You will need to create a separate class to hold your new exception.
Modify your code to catch the FileNotFoundException and throw a FileMissingException. In your main() catch the FileMissingException and print the message.from the exception.

The program is becoming a little bit disorganized because of all I have to accomplish. Keep in mind I am in intro to programming so there is a lot I don't understand but I try my best. Any tips you guys give me would be very helpful.

The new code I have written:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*; 
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class TextFile 
    {
    private static ArrayList<String> filesData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    System.out.println("Input file: ");
    String fileNameInput = console.nextLine();
    // Construct the Scanner and PrintWriter objects for reading and writing
    File inputFile = new File(fileNameInput);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

    do
    {
        // Asks the user what they would like to do with the file info based on number input.
        System.out.println("Please enter the number for your choice: ");
        System.out.println("1. Display the contents of the file.");
        System.out.println("2. Reverse the contents of the file.");
        System.out.println("3. Write the contents of the file to a new file.");
        System.out.println("0. Exits the program");
        int num = console.nextInt();
        console.nextLine();
        switch(num)
        {
            case 0:
                in.close();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 1:
                while (in.hasNext())
                {
                    String lines = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(lines);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                displayReverse(inputFile);
                break;
            case 3:
                outputFile(inputFile);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }while (true);
}
public static void displayReverse(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    while (in.hasNext())
    {
        String text = in.next();
        filesData.add(text);
    }
    for (int i = filesData.size(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.print(filesData.get(i - 1) + " ");
    }
    in.close();
}
public static void outputFile(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException
{       
    System.out.println("Name your new file(hint: do not worry about a complete path here!): ");
    String outputFileName = inputFile.getParentFile() + "\\" + console.nextLine();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    PrintWriter outFiles = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
    while (in.hasNext())
    {
        String line = in.next();
        outFiles.print(line + " ");
    }
    outFiles.close();
    in.close();
}
```

}

Comment: To read and write (not to the same file) in the same program you simply open both files the same way you would if only reading or only writing.  You just have to keep track of which is which (and don't forget to close the output file when done).  You can make your "reverse a line" algorithm into a separate method so it can be called from either the "display reversed" or "output reversed file" path.

Comment: (And please, folks, don't do the guy's homework for him -- just give him the necessary hints.)

Comment: @Hot Licks Don't worry I closed the output file. Otherwise the file would get corrupted as my teacher told us. I was thinking of doing an algorithm to reverse the file text but decided to use the arraylist way like my teacher suggested and got it to work for now.